# how many embeddings into $\overline{\mathbf{Q}}$ does a given number field have

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Fix an algebraic closure $\overline{\mathbf{Q}}$ of the rational numbers.

Let $\mathbf{Q}\subset K$ be a number field.

I know that the degree $[K:\mathbf{Q} ]$ equals the number of embeddings of $K$ into the complex numbers.

Does $[K:\mathbf{Q}]$ also equal to the number of embeddings of $K$ into $\overline{\mathbf{Q}}$?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suppose that by $\overline{\Bbb Q}$ you mean the subfield of $\Bbb C$ consisting of the algebraic numbers.

If $F\subset L$ and $F\subset L^\prime$ are fields, any map of fields $L\rightarrow L^\prime$ which is the identity on $F$ will send elements that are algebraic over $F$ to elements that are algebraic over $F$. This is a straightforward consequence of the definition of homomorphism.

In an extension ${\Bbb Q}\subset K$ of finite degree, *all* elements are algebraic. Thus the image of an embedding $K\rightarrow\Bbb C$ must be entirely included in $\overline{\Bbb Q}$.

Comment: This is true even if the degree is not finite, as long as the extension is algebraic. But *number field* usually means finite extension.